# How to solve a simple boundary value problem for TISE on python

Tags: python, physics, ode

I am trying to solve the TISE for an infinite potential well `V=0` on the interval `[0,L]`. The exercise gives us that the value of the wavefunction and its derivative at `0` is `0,1` respectively. This allows us to using the `scipy.integrate.odeint` function in order to solve the problem for a given energy value.

The task is to now find the energy eigenvalues given the further boundary condition that the wavefunction at `L` is `0`, using a root finding function on python. I have done some research and could only find something called the 'shooting method' which I cannot figure out how to implement. Also, I have come across the solve BVP scipy function, however I can't seem to understand what exactly goes in the second input for this function (boundary condition residuals)

```
m_el   = 9.1094e-31      # mass of electron in [kg]
hbar   = 1.0546e-34      # Planck's constant over 2 pi [Js]
e_el   = 1.6022e-19      # electron charge in [C]
L_bohr = 5.2918e-11      # Bohr radius [m]

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def eqn(y, x, energy):              #array of first order ODE's     
    y0 = y[1]
    y1 = -2*m_el*energy*y[0]/hbar**2

    return np.array([y0,y1])

def solve(energy, func):           #use of odeint
    p0 = 0
    dp0 = 1
    x = np.linspace(0,L_bohr,1000)
    init = np.array([p0,dp0])
    ysolve = odeint(func, init, x, args=(energy,))
    return ysolve[-1,0]
```

The method here is to input eqn as func in solve(energy,func). L_bohr is the L value in this problem. We are trying to numerically find the energy eigenvalues using some scipy method

Comment: So what happens when you add a line below that is `print(solve(0.1,eqn))` or substituting 0.1 for some other energy?  You might find some clues in the odeint documentation https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html

Comment: you get the ode solved for energy = 0.1 for 1000 x values up to L? however this doesn't match the final boundary condition

Comment: So can you more precisely state your question, then? Are you getting an error somewhere?

Comment: I need to find the energy eigenvalues using some scipy method

Comment: Are you required to do this numerically, or can you use the fact that there's an analytical solution to the Schrodinger equation in an infinite well?

Answer (score 0):

For all the other solvers in scipy the argument order `x,y`, and even in `odeint` one can use this order by giving the option `tfirst=True`. Thus change to

```
def eqn(x, y, energy):              #array of first order ODE's     
    y0, y1 = y
    y2 = -2*m_el*energy*y0/hbar**2

    return [y1,y2]
```

For the BVP solver you have to think of the energy parameter as an 
extra state component with zero derivative, thus adding a third slot 
in the boundary conditions. Scipy's `solve_bvp` allows to keep it as parameter,
so that you get 3 slots in the boundary conditions, allowing to fix the first derivative at `x=0` to select one non-trivial solution from the eigenspace.

```
def bc(y0, yL, E):
    return [ y0[0], y0[1]-1, yL[0] ]
```

Next construct an initial state that is close to the suspected ground state and call the solver

```
x0 = np.linspace(0,L_bohr,6);
y0 = [ x0*(1-x0/L_bohr), 1-2*x0/L_bohr ]
E0 = 134*e_el

sol = solve_bvp(eqn, bc, x0, y0, p=[E0])
print(sol.message, "  E=", sol.p[0]/e_el," eV")
```

and then produce the plot

```
x = np.linspace(0,L_bohr,1000)
plt.plot(x/L_bohr, sol.sol(x)[0]/L_bohr,'-+', ms=1)
plt.grid()
```

> `The algorithm converged to the desired accuracy.   E= 134.29310361903723  eV`

[image: ground state wave]